# python bs4 scripts work on command prompt and not ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, beautifulsoup

I have a very basic web scraper made with bs4 and requests and it works perfectly fine when i run it on command prompt but when i try to run it on ubuntu it doesn't return anything.

```
def scrape():
    queryURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=oranges"
    headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
    }
    r = requests.get(queryURL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    a = soup.find_all('div', class_='r')

    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        urls = []
        for result in soup.find_all('div', class_='r'):
            anchors = result.find_all('a')
            if anchors:
                link = anchors[0]['href']
                urls.append(link)
        for url in urls:
            print(url)
scrape()
```

[On command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQxhB.png)

[On ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdqB6.png)

Comment: edit code and use special button `{}` to format code. You have wrong indentations.

Comment: use print to see what you get in variables. Google doesn't like scripts and it has big money to create complex system to recognize bots/scripts and block them - and maybe it block your script when you run it from some IP or when you run it too often, etc.

Comment: i did use {} i copied and pasted. it just wont indent it right

Comment: you have to use special button `{}` after pasting code - it adds 4 spaces to all lines and then it displays corectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using a residential proxy.